# Nest API Corrupts OAuth 2.0 State Parameter

Tags: oauth, nest-api

I'm using Nest as an Authentication Provider for Salesforce, with the intention of calling the Nest API from Force.com. The problem I have is that Nest corrupts the `state` parameter during the OAuth 2.0 flow.

This is the redirect from Salesforce to Nest. I've inserted line breaks for clarity:

```
https://home.nest.com/login/oauth2?
    response_type=code&
    client_id=16188153-52f1-4ac9-93ee-83ccab5cbd2f&
    redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.salesforce.com%2Fservices%2Fauthcallback%2F00DE0000000cjOBMAY%2FNest&
    state=jMG%2F2bzDEPisWyKsH7yVPHCrHdHxRAzYhG3Aq7VBF%2FrBLmW49eGj3DEzCLg0aGIvbOadXUxf1pwiDIPupqOMTZ%2BQbuThvTf58y2zXHwDNcoAvg%3D%3D
```

Note the 'percent encoding' in the `state` parameter

This is the redirect back to Salesforce:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/services/authcallback/00DE0000000cjOBMAY/Nest?
    state=jMG/2bzDEPisWyKsH7yVPHCrHdHxRAzYhG3Aq7VBF/rBLmW49eGj3DEzCLg0aGIvbOadXUxf1pwiDIPupqOMTZ+QbuThvTf58y2zXHwDNcoAvg==&
    code=UCMG2TEF9S69CQX2
```

Notice, `state` is no longer URL encoded. And, in particular, since it contains a `+` character, when Salesforce decodes it, that `+` is interpreted as a space, and the state doesn't match what Salesforce sent, so authentication fails.

Nest - please fix this!

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place for bug reports, Nest provides other channels like the Nest community and email for reporting issues.

Comment: Cool - wasn't aware of that. https://developer.nest.com/ only mentions StackOverflow.